# Javascript: About Return()() format tail recursion in Fibonacci function

Tags: javascript, return, tail-recursion

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    return (function(a, b, i) {
        return (i < n) ? arguments.callee(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
    })(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Hey, I am a rookie, I could understand the math logical part of this function, what I did not understand is the parameter passing progress, it passes (1,1,1) to the function(a b i), which seems not very normal.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    return (function(a, b, i) {
        return (i < n) ? arguments.callee(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
    })
    regular function pass a parameter like the way function(1 1 1)
}
```

I can not understand this, I tried to abstract it into finally the

```
function fibonacci(n){
    return()()
}
```

format, but how could this pass the parameter, I guess it is something about the return call could not handle a function call after it which also works in it.

So, is there some basic stuff I havent learnt? Like some default format like the entries in MDN?

Thnx a lot.

Comment: It's almost impossible to understand what you're talking about. What is confusing about passing 3 parameters to a function that's defined as expecting 3 parameters?

Comment: Also, note that using `arguments.callee` is a pretty bad idea, so you should be suspicious of wherever you found this code sample.

Comment: `return (function (a, b) { ... }}(1,2);` is equivalent to `function foo(a,b) { ... }; return foo(1,2);`. We just replaced the variable (`foo`) with the function definition itself and removed the function name. This has nothing to do with `return`. Simplified but equivalent example: Instead of writing `var pattern = /\d/; var result = pattern.test(value);` you could use the expression literal directly, without introducing a new variable `pattern`: `var result = /\d/.test(value);`.

Comment: @Felix Kling thnx, now I get it.

Comment: @FelixKling could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/29663125/251311 ? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> return (function(a, b, i) {
>     return (i < n) ? arguments.callee(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
> })(1, 1, 1);
> ```

is an anonymous function expression that is immediately invoked. The parenthesis around it [are not required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15023560/1048572).

The usage of [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) is deprecated, this would better have been written with a named function expression:

```
return (function recurse(a, b, i) {
    return (i < n) ? recurse(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
})(1, 1, 1);
```

which is equivalent to the function declaration and invocation

```
function recurse(a, b, i) {
    return (i < n) ? recurse(b, a + b, i + 1) : a;
}
return recurse(1, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your final abstraction is wrong. It's not `return()()` but it is:

```
return      ( function(){} )()
```

Note that the `()` does not belong to `return` since `return` is not a function. In this case, `()` act as grouping parenthesis. In the same way when you use it like:

```
return (1+1)*2
```

Here, adding `*2` behind the `()` works because the parenthesis is not part of a function invocation but is instead used as a grouping operator. Or more precisely, an expression evaluator.

You see, how `(1+1)*2` works is that the `()` is recognized as not being part of a function call, thus it's contents are treated as an expression. So it is parsed as:

```
temporary_variable = 1+1;
temporary_variable * 2;
```

In the same way, `(function(){})()` is parsed as:

```
temporary_variable = function(){};
temporary_variable();
```

Thus, the whole thing is basically doing this:

```
function f (n) {
    temporary_variable = function (a,b,i) {
        /* ... */
    }
    return temporary_variable(1,1,1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to whoever edited my answer but I really wanted to emphasize that functions can be assigned to variables just like values. Values can't be assigned to values. Therefore naming the variable "variable" is more illustrative than naming it "value"