# Why are Objects not Iterable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Why are objects not iterable by default?

**I see questions all the time related to iterating objects, the common solution being to iterate over an object's properties and accessing the values within an object that way. This seems so common that it makes me wonder why objects themselves aren't iterable.**

Statements like the ES6 [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) would be nice to use for objects by default. Because these features are only available for special "iterable objects" which don't include `{}` objects, we have to go through hoops to make this work for objects we want to use it for.

> The for...of statement creates a loop Iterating over **iterable objects**
>   (including Array, Map, Set, arguments object and so on)...

For example using an ES6 [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```
var example = {a: {e: 'one', f: 'two'}, b: {g: 'three'}, c: {h: 'four', i: 'five'}};

function* entries(obj) {
   for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
     yield [key, obj[key]];
   }
}

for (let [key, value] of entries(example)) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
  for (let [key, value] of entries(value)) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

The above properly logs data in the order I expect it to when I run the code in Firefox (which supports [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla)):

[image: output of hacky for...of]

**By default, `{}` objects are not iterable, but why? Would the disadvantages outweigh the potential benefits of objects being iterable? What are the issues associated with this?**

In addition, because `{}` objects are different from "Array-like" collections and "iterable objects" such as [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), [`HtmlCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), they can't be converted into Arrays.

For example:

`var argumentsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

or be used with Array methods:

`Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function (element) {})`.

**Besides the questions I have above, I would love to see a working example on how to make `{}` objects into iterables, especially from those who have mentioned the `[Symbol.iterator]`.** This should allow these new `{}` "iterable objects" to use statements like `for...of`. Also, I wonder if making objects iterable allow them to be converted into Arrays.

I tried the below code, but I get a `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`.

```
var example = {a: {e: 'one', f: 'two'}, b: {g: 'three'}, c: {h: 'four', i: 'five'}};

// I want to be able to use "for...of" for the "example" object.
// I also want to be able to convert the "example" object into an Array.
example[Symbol.iterator] = function* (obj) {
   for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
     yield [key, obj[key]];
   }
};

for (let [key, value] of example) { console.log(value); } // error
console.log([...example]); // error
```

Comment: Anything that has a `Symbol.iterator` property is an iterable. So you'd just have to implement that property. One *possible* explanation for why objects are not iterable could be that this would imply *everything* was iterable, since everything is an object (except primitives of course). However, what does it mean to iterate over a function or a regular expression object?

Comment: What's your actual question here? Why did ECMA make the decisions it did?

Comment: Since objects have NO guaranteed order of their properties, I wonder if that breaks from the definition of an iterable which you would expect to have a predictable order?

Comment: To get an authoritative answer for "why", you should ask at https://esdiscuss.org/

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm not sure that's true anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29664067/218196 (but I could be misinterpreting the spec).

Comment: @FelixKling - is that post about ES6?  You should probably edit it to say what version you're talking about because "upcoming version of ECMAScript" doesn't work very well over time.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I don't think [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) requires a predictable iteration order?  As I read it a valid iterator is anything that 1) returns values one at a time, and 2) knows when it's returned the last value.  That would permit even iterators that return elements in a random/arbitrary order.  Though perhaps a better example is Sets and Maps in Java, which are iterable even though many implementations lack a predictable iteration order.

Comment: I would like to know what the implications are for an object being an iterable and why there is a need for classification for "iterable objects", which ties into the question about why objects are not iterable. I'm looking for any insight, as I am far from an expert in JS internals. I think this would be wonderful for the community because I see questions all the time regarding iteration and objects, the common solution being to iterate over the object's properties and accessing the values that way.

Comment: @boombox - I think that's something you'd have to take to the people who actually make decisions about the spec.  If I were to guess, however, I'd say they're trying to address the limitations of `for...in` (for instance, try that on an array and you won't just get the array elements, but also all of the member functions that exist on `Array`) in a way that won't break existing code.  And I assume objects would be excluded from that because including them would require including a built-in `Symbol.iterator` property against all objects, which would break `for...in` loops in existing code.

Comment: @FelixKling what happens if one deletes and then creates the same property again on an object? Can the two versions of the object treated as equal? From the post it appears their properties will not be iterated in the same order.

Comment: @Dinesh: Yep, seems like that is the case. At least that's how it works in Chrome.

Comment: Why all the hubb bubb here? The first comment from @FelixKling seemed to answer the question. In fact the OP linked to the Mozilla docs for for...of and if you followed the link about iterable objects it answered the question.

Comment: @jfriend00: The order of properties in an object is indeed now specified by ECMAScript 6 / ECMAScript 2015. It wasn't before, but [it is now](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Since you have no ability to actually change the order of ES6 properties on an existing object, I've yet to find an actual use for this.  It still seems like if you want to manage order, then use an array.

Comment: @jfriend00: *"if you want to manage order, then use an array"* Totally with you there. :-) But you *can* change property order: [Delete and add back](http://jsfiddle.net/kkfz3tod/), and the property goes at the end (provided it's not an array index). That fiddle works in current Firefox and Chrome. Not in IE11; I don't have my IE Edge VM handy...

Comment: @jfriend00: Look again at the fiddle: Yes, you *can* change the order of ES6 properties on an existing object. But again, like you, I can't see why I'd want to.

Comment: Why are you writing a custom entries function in the first place to get iterable key value pairs when Object.entries() is available and better performant?

Answer (score 57):

I'll give this a try.  Note that I'm not affiliated with ECMA and have no visibility into their decision-making process, so I cannot definitively say *why* they have or have not done anything.  However, I'll state my assumptions and take my best shot.

**1.  Why add a `for...of` construct in the first place?**

JavaScript already includes a `for...in` construct that can be used to iterate the properties of an object.  However, it's [not really a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243778/609251), as it enumerates all of the properties on an object and tends to only work predictably in simple cases.

It breaks down in more complex cases (including with arrays, where its use tends to be either [discouraged or thoroughly obfuscated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) by the safeguards needed to for use `for...in` with an array *correctly*).  You can work around that by using `hasOwnProperty` (among other things), but that's a bit clunky and inelegant.

So therefore my assumption is that the `for...of` construct is being added to address the deficiencies associated with the `for...in` construct, and provide greater utility and flexibility when iterating things.  People tend to treat `for...in` as a `forEach` loop that can be generally applied to any collection and produce sane results in any possible context, but that's not what happens.  The `for...of` loop fixes that.

I also assume that it's important for existing ES5 code to run under ES6 and produce the same result as it did under ES5, so breaking changes cannot be made, for instance, to the behavior of the `for...in` construct.

**2.  How does `for...of` work?**

The [reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) is useful for this part.  Specifically, an object is considered `iterable` if it defines the `Symbol.iterator` property.

The property-definition should be a function that returns the items in the collection, one, by, one, and sets a flag indicating whether or not there are more items to fetch.  Predefined implementations are provided for [some object-types](http://jsfiddle.net/rncr3ppz/1/), and it's relatively clear that using `for...of` simply delegates to the iterator function.

This approach is useful, as it makes it very straightforward to provide your own iterators.  I might say the approach could have presented practical issues due to its reliance upon defining a property where previously there was none, except from what I can tell that's not the case as the new property is essentially ignored unless you deliberately go looking for it (i.e. it will not present in `for...in` loops as a key, etc.).  So that's not the case.

Practical non-issues aside, it may have been considered conceptually controversial to start all objects off with a new pre-defined property, or to implicitly say that "every object is a collection".

**3.  Why are objects not `iterable` using `for...of` by default?**

My *guess* is that this is a combination of:

1. Making all objects `iterable` by default may have been considered unacceptable because it adds a property where previously there was none, or because an object isn't (necessarily) a collection.  As Felix notes, "what does it mean to iterate over a function or a regular expression object"?
2. Simple objects can already be iterated using `for...in`, and it's not clear what a built-in iterator implementation could have done differently/better than the existing `for...in` behavior.  So even if #1 is wrong and adding the property was acceptable, it may not have been seen as *useful*.
3. Users who want to make their objects `iterable` can easily do so, by defining the `Symbol.iterator` property.
4. The ES6 spec also provides a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) type, which *is* `iterable` by default and has some other small advantages over using a plain object as a `Map`.

There's even an example provided for #3 in the reference documentation:

```
var myIterable = {};
myIterable[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
};

for (var value of myIterable) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Given that objects can easily be made `iterable`, that they can already be iterated using `for...in`, and that there's likely not clear agreement on what a default object iterator should do (if what it does is meant to be somehow different from what `for...in` does), it seems reasonable enough that objects were not made `iterable` by default.

Note that your example code can be rewritten using `for...in`:

```
for (let levelOneKey in object) {
    console.log(levelOneKey);         //  "example"
    console.log(object[levelOneKey]); // {"random":"nest","another":"thing"}

    var levelTwoObj = object[levelOneKey];
    for (let levelTwoKey in levelTwoObj ) {
        console.log(levelTwoKey);   // "random"
        console.log(levelTwoObj[levelTwoKey]); // "nest"
    }
}
```

...or you can also make your object `iterable` in the way you want by doing something like the following (or you can make *all* objects `iterable` by assigning to `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` instead):

```
obj = { 
    a: '1', 
    b: { something: 'else' }, 
    c: 4, 
    d: { nested: { nestedAgain: true }}
};

obj[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    var keys = [];
    var ref = this;
    for (var key in this) {
        //note:  can do hasOwnProperty() here, etc.
        keys.push(key);
    }

    return {
        next: function() {
            if (this._keys && this._obj && this._index < this._keys.length) {
                var key = this._keys[this._index];
                this._index++;
                return { key: key, value: this._obj[key], done: false };
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        },
        _index: 0,
        _keys: keys,
        _obj: ref
    };
};
```

You can play with that here (in Chrome, at lease):  http://jsfiddle.net/rncr3ppz/5/

**Edit**

And in response to your updated question, yes, it is possible to convert an `iterable` to an array, using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in ES6.

However, this doesn't seem to be working in Chrome yet, or at least I cannot get it to work in my jsFiddle.  In theory it should be as simple as:

```
var array = [...myIterable];
```

Comment: Why not just do `obj[Symbol.iterator] = obj[Symbol.enumerate]` in your last example?

Comment: @Bergi - Because I didn't see that in the docs (and am not seeing that property described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)).  Though one argument in favor of defining the iterator explicitly is that it makes it easy to enforce a specific iteration order, should that be required.  If iteration order is not important (or if the default order is fine) and the one-line shortcut works, there's little reason not to take the more concise approach, however.

Comment: Oops, `[[enumerate]]` is not a well-known symbol (@@enumerate) but an internal method. I would have to be `obj[Symbol.iterator] = function(){ return Reflect.enumerate(this) }`

Comment: What use are all these guesses, when the actual process of discussion is well documented? It's very odd that you would say "So therefore my assumption is that the for...of construct is being added to address the deficiencies associated with the for...in construct." No. It was added to support a general way to iterate over anything, and is part of a wide-ranging set of new features including iterables themselves, generators, and maps and sets. It's hardly meant as a replacement or upgrade to `for...in`, which has a different purpose--to iterate across the **properties** of an object.

Comment: @torazaburo - "It was added to support a general way to iterate over anything".  Yes, but _why_?  The problem is, that's what many people assume `for...in` to be, much to their own frustration.  I'd find it hard to believe that the people behind ES6 weren't aware of that fact, the issues that it causes, the previous (and occasionally, [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)) attempts at adding similar features, and the language's dire need of a _working_ `forEach` loop.

Comment: Good point emphasizing again that not every object is a collection. Objects have been used as such for a long time, because it was a very convenient, but ultimately, they are not really collections. That's what we have `Map` for now.

Answer (score 11):

`Object`s don't implement the iteration protocols in Javascript for very good reasons. There are two levels at which object properties can be iterated over in JavaScript:

- the program level
- the data level

### Program Level Iteration

When you iterate over an object at the program level you examine a portion of the structure of your program. It is a reflective operation. Let's illustrate this statement with an array type, which is usually iterated over at the data level:

```js
const xs = [1,2,3];
xs.f = function f() {};

for (let i in xs) console.log(xs[i]); // logs `f` as well
```

We just examined the program level of `xs`. Since arrays store data sequences, we are regularly interested in the data level only. `for..in` evidently makes no sense in connection with arrays and other "data-oriented" structures in most cases. That is the reason why ES2015 has introduced `for..of` and the iterable protocol.

### Data Level Iteration

Does that mean that we can simply distinguish the data from the program level by distinguishing functions from primitive types? No, because functions can also be data in Javascript:

- `Array.prototype.sort` for instance expects a function to perform a certain sort algorithm
- Thunks like `() => 1 + 2` are just functional wrappers for lazily evaluated values

Besides primitive values can represent the program level as well:

- `[].length` for instance is a `Number` but represents the length of an array and thus belongs to the program domain

That means that we can't distinguish the program and data level by merely checking types.

---

It is important to understand that the implementation of the iteration protocols for plain old Javascript objects would rely on the data level. But as we've just seen, a reliable distinction between data and program level iteration is not possible.

With `Array`s this distinction is trivial: Every element with an integer-like key is a data element. `Object`s have an equivalent feature: The `enumerable` descriptor. But is it really advisable to rely on this? I believe it is not! The meaning of the `enumerable` descriptor is too blurry.

### Conclusion

**There is no meaningful way to implement the iteration protocols for objects, because not every object is a collection.**

If object properties were iterable by default, program and data level were mixed-up. Since every composite type in Javascript is based on plain objects this would apply for `Array` and `Map` as well.

`for..in`, `Object.keys`, `Reflect.ownKeys` etc. can be used for both reflection and data iteration, a clear distinction is regularly not possible. If you're not careful, you end up quickly with meta programming and weird dependencies. The `Map` abstract data type effectively ends the conflating of program and data level. I believe `Map` is the most significant achievement in ES2015, even if `Promise`s are much more exciting.

Comment: +1, I think "There is no meaningful way to implement the iteration protocols for objects, because not every object is a collection." sums it up.

Comment: I don't think that's a good argument. If your object isn't a collection, why are you trying to loop over it? It doesn't *matter* that not every object is a collection, because you won't be attempting to iterate over ones that aren't.

Comment: Actually, every object _is_ a collection, and it’s not up to the language to decide whether or not the collection is coherent. Arrays and Maps can also collect unrelated values. The point is that you can iterate over the keys of any object regardless of their use, so you are one step away from iterating over their values. If you were talking about a language which statically types array (or any other collection) values, you could talk about such restrictions, but not JavaScript.

Comment: That argument that every object isn't a collection doesn't make sense.  You're assuming that an iterator only has one purpose (to iterate a collection).  The default iterator on an object would be an iterator of the properties of the object, no matter what those properties represent (whether a collection or something else).  As Manngo said, if your object doens't represent a collection, then it's up to the programmer to not treat it like a collection.  Maybe they just want to iterate the properties on the object for some debug output?  There are lots of other reasons besides a collection.

Answer (score 11):

I was also bothered with this question.

Then I came up with an idea of using `Object.entries({...})`, it returns an `Array` which is an `Iterable`.

Also, Dr. Axel Rauschmayer posted an excellent answer on this.
See [Why plain objects are NOT iterable](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_iteration.html#sec_plain-objects-not-iterable)

Comment: This is brilliant. Just what I was looking for. 

Object.entries({...}).forEach(function() {... }); 

works perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

I guess the question should be "why is there no **built-in** object iteration?

Adding iterability to objects themselves could conceivably have unintended consequences, and no, there is no way to guarantee order, but writing an iterator is as simple as

```
function* iterate_object(o) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
        yield [keys[i], o[keys[i]]];
    }
}
```

Then

```
for (var [key, val] of iterate_object({a: 1, b: 2})) {
    console.log(key, val);
}

a 1
b 2
```

Comment: thanks torazaburo. i have revised my question. i would love to see an example using `[Symbol.iterator]` as well as if you could expand on those unintended consequences.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make all objects iterable globally:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, Symbol.iterator, {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function * (){
        for(let key in this){
            if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                yield [key, this[key]];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't globally add methods to native objects. This is a terrible idea that will bite you, and anyone that uses your code, in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

This is the latest approach (which works in chrome canary)

```
var files = {
    '/root': {type: 'directory'},
    '/root/example.txt': {type: 'file'}
};

for (let [key, {type}] of Object.entries(files)) {
    console.log(type);
}
```

Yes `entries` is now a method thats part of Object :)

## edit

After looking more into it, it seems you could do the following

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function * () {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this)) {
        yield {key, value}; // or [key, value]
    }
};
```

so you can now do this

```
for (const {key, value:{type}} of files) {
    console.log(key, type);
}
```

## edit2

Back to your original example, if you wanted to use the above prototype method it would like like this

```
for (const {key, value:item1} of example) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(item1);
    for (const {key, value:item2} of item1) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(item2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is not an answer to the question **why?** but I have adapted Jack Slocum’s answer above in light of BT’s comments to something which can be used to make an Object iterable.

```
var iterableProperties={
    enumerable: false,
    value: function * () {
        for(let key in this) if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)) yield this[key];
    }
};

var fruit={
    'a': 'apple',
    'b': 'banana',
    'c': 'cherry'
};
Object.defineProperty(fruit,Symbol.iterator,iterableProperties);
for(let v of fruit) console.log(v);
```

Not quite as convenient as it should have been, but it’s workable, especially if you have multiple objects:

```
var instruments={
    'a': 'accordion',
    'b': 'banjo',
    'c': 'cor anglais'
};
Object.defineProperty(instruments,Symbol.iterator,iterableProperties);
for(let v of instruments) console.log(v);
```

And, because every one is entitled to an opinion, I can’t see why Objects are not already iterable either. If you can polyfill them as above, or use `for … in` then I can’t see a simple argument.

One possible suggestion is that what is iterable is a *type* of object, so it is possible that iterable has been limited to a subset of objects just in case some other objects explode in the attempt.