# Why can't I iterate the properties of my ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, ecmascript-6

In the Node.js REPL:

```
> var map = new Map();
undefined
> map['foo'] = 'bar';
'bar'
> map['bar'] = 'baz';
'baz'
> map
Map { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }
> map.forEach(console.log);
undefined
```

As you can see, the `foo` and `bar` keys are clearly defined within `map`, but when I try to iterate over them with `Map.prototype.forEach`, nothing happens - but [according to MDN, it should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_forEach()). Note also that `Map.prototype.forEach` *is defined*, so it's not just that this method hasn't been implemented yet. I've also tried using a `for ... of ...` loop, with the same result - the code I provide to be run for each iteration doesn't actually run, even though [it should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Iterating_Maps_with_for..of).

I'm on Node.js v4.4.4. I searched the web for "javascript map isn't iterable node" and the like, with no luck.

What's going on here?

Comment: `Map` objects don't have properties, they have entries. Create it using `new Map([['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'baz']])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not 100% positive, but I think you need to use `map.set` with `Maps`.

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('foo', 'bar');
map.set('bar', 'baz');
map.forEach(console.log);
```

This will log out each of the items that you are looking for. Because the `Map.prototype.forEach` is looking for iterable properties, you need to use the `set()` function to set those iterable properties.

Comment: what in the world? this worked (will accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed), but I can't _imagine_ why it's this way - or, for that matter, why the `map[key]` syntax appeared to "work", but not really, in such a confusing way. anyway, thanks!

Comment: oh I see. it's because I was setting a property on the Map, whereas `map.set` is setting the key _inside_ the Map... if that makes sense.

Comment: Because a map is an `Object`, you can duck-punch any property that you want onto it. Just like you can say `[].foo = "bar"`, to duck-punch properties onto an array, you can do the same with a Map, or a Function. Thus, it didn't error when you tried to do it. However, Maps use the `Iterator` functionality from ES6, which means that in order for you to get the iterable stuff to work, you need to set values using `.set()` instead of using dotNotation or bracketNotation to set the value. This is how maps work.

Answer (score 1):

`Map` is an **abstract data type**. Applying the `Map` constructor with `new` creates a normal object of course. But the `Map` itself is abstracted behind its API (`Map.prototype.get/set/has/clear` etc.):

```js
const map = new Map([["key1", 1], ["key2", 2]]);

// you can mutate the Map object:
map["foo"] = "bar";
map.bar = "baz";

console.log( map );

// but you need to use the Map API to mutate the Map itself:
map.set("key3", 3);

map.forEach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Note that this is actually the benefit of the new Map type: It separates the [data from the program level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38777177/6445533).

Answer (score 0):

We can use **for(){...} operator** to iterate ES6 Map

```
let map0 = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3]
]);

let map1 = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of myMap) {
    map1.set('_' + k, v * 2);    
}
```

resulted in

```
{'_a' => 2, '_b' => 4, '_c' => 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use **.map()** iterator, we can use a simple trick for Maps, because there is no such operation for Maps as map(). 
The approach from [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html) is:
* Convert the map into an array of [key,value] pairs.
* Map or filter the array.
* Convert the result back to a map.

Example:

```
let map0 = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3]
]);

const map1 = new Map(
  [...map0]
  .map(([k, v]) => ['_' + k, v * 2 ])
);
```

resulted in

```
{'_a' => 2, '_b' => 4, '_c' => 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who tries to convert a reactive Map<> property (in Vue.js) into an array, use Array.from(). Reactive properties won't map "as is":

```js
const array = Array.from(reactiveMap.entries()).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
```