# How do I make work filter function on Class extended from Array

Tags: javascript

I try to create a custom Array class by extending the generic Array one. On this class I want to create a custom find / filter. When I call the custom `find` it works well, but when I call the `filter` I get a problem with the iterator. 
There is my code

```
class MyClass extends Array {
  constructor(inArray){
    super();
    this.push(...inArray);
  }

  myFind(callback) {
    return this.find(callback);
  }

  myFilter(callback) {
    return this.filter(callback);
  }
}
//Works
console.log(new MyClass(["a","b"]).myFind(item => item === "a"));
//Do not work
console.log(new MyClass(["a","b"]).myFilter(item => item === "a"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Objects not Iterable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886552/why-are-objects-not-iterable-in-javascript)

Comment: No because my class extends `Array`. This behavior is due to `new this.constructor(0);` called in filter prototype as @javimovi and @Jonas Wilms explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is, that `.filter(...)` creates a new array. And that array is very special, as it got the same type as the array it is called on:

```
 (new MyClass(["a", "b"])).filter(/*...*/) // MyClass(...)
```

so when you call `filter`, it calls the arrays constructor by passing the arrays length first:

```
 Array.prototype.filter = function(cb) {
  const result = new this.constructor(0); // <---
  for(const el of this) 
    if(cb(el) result.push(el);
  return result;
};
```

Now that constructor is:

```
 constructor(inArray){ // inArray = 0
   super();
   this.push(...inArray); // ...0
}
```

and spreading `0` is impossible. To resolve that, make the constructor behave just as the arrays constructor, or just don't add your own constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**Try add:**

```
class MyClass extends Array {
  constructor(inArray){
    super();
    if(inArray !== 0 ) this.push(...inArray); // Condition
  }

  myFind(callback) {
    return this.find(callback);
  }

  myFilter(callback) {
    return this.filter(callback);
  }
}
```

> The problem is that it is very dangerous to overwrite the ARRAY class
>   constructor, the function of the `filter` is to create an empty
>   array and then fill it with the matches it finds, so when creating an
>   empty array `inArray === 0`, this causes `this.push (... inArray)` give an 
>   error.