# Can the JavaScript ES6 Spread operator be used with array-like objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I found the Spread operator can be used with `arguments`:

```
function foo() {
    [...arr] = arguments;
    console.log(arr, Array.isArray(arr));
}

foo(1, 3, 5);

// note that we could also use function foo(...args) { } to begin with
```

But not with an object that is array-like (it would throw an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`):

```
let obj = { 0: "abc", 1: 3.14, length: 2 };

[...arr] = obj;
console.log(arr, Array.isArray(arr));
```

So can the Spread operator be used with array-like objects?

As a side note, the following could both make an array:

```
let obj = { 0: "abc", 1: 3.14, length: 2 };
let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
console.log(arr, Array.isArray(arr));

let arr2 = Array.from(obj);
console.log(arr2, Array.isArray(arr2));
```

Comment: Spread syntax works on any object that implements the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol)

Comment: This is a pedantic comment, but that's what Stack Overflow is all about: the `...` syntax is not an "operator"; spread syntax is not part of the expression grammar.

Comment: Seems like it'd be possible to create a function that'd return an Iterable object wrapper around a plain "dumb" object.

Comment: As a side note, does this actually have a duplicate target or should I go ahead and write an actual answer?

Comment: You can spread both iterable and non-iterable objects but it means something depending on both the source and the destination.

Comment: I guess `[...arr] = Array.from(obj)` is close enough then?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I just did a couple of searches for a dup and failed. Closest I found was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886552/why-are-objects-not-iterable-in-javascript/29891072#29891072 which shows how to write a wrapper function.

Comment: @Barmar this seems to be the same as the question in part 3 of that answer, in my opinion at least.

Comment: @LukStorms That's simply superfluous, just do `const arr = Array.from(obj)`

Comment: @Bergi  I know it's super silly.  ;) But `[...arr]` is 1 character less than `const arr` ;p  Oh darn, `let arr` is the better golf-code.  Darn, "let objects be objects, don't iterate them" my granny always told me.

Comment: @LukStorms I had expected there was a `const`/`let`/`var` in front of `[...arr]` as well. Without it, it's an assignment to an undeclared variable, and would throw an exception in strict mode. The sloppy code in the OP actually creates a global variable `arr`.